# html5 Canvas - FillRect() incorrectly draws the rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm building a visualization of a 24 hour period with this bar.
It starts at midnight on the left, and ends at midnight on the right.

The canvas width is 1440 = 24hrs * 60 minutes = 1 pixel per minute.

First, I fill the whole canvas with yellow, to signify daytime.
Next, I add 4 hours at the beginning & end, to signify night time.
That part works fine.

Next, I am trying to add an event that lasts 4 minutes, in blue.  It should be a very small sliver, but it's huge.

What am I doing wrong???

https://jsfiddle.net/zuehejjm/

```
<html>
<canvas id="myCanvas" 
  width="1440" height="60"
  class="img-responsive"
  style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,1440,60);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#eeeeee";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,240,60);
    ctx.fillRect(1200,0,1440,60);

    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fillRect(540,0,544,60);

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [docs for `fillRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect)

```
fillRect(x, y, width, height)
```

You should use 4 instead of 544

```
ctx.fillRect(540, 0, 4, 60);
```