# Extra operations being done in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to program a simple snake game in js when I got to drawing the snake, the boxes were the wrong dimensions, and with some alert boxes, I found that the calculation (5*100)+9 was resulting in 5009, but only when another calculation was performed on the same line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<style>
  canvas {
    background-color: #000;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <canvas id="Canvas" width=1000px height=1000px>
  </canvas>
</body>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var sX = 5; //snake head x
  var sY = 5; //snake head y
  var sDir = 1 //0n1e2s3w, snake direction
  //while(1){

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //get context
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0f0";
  ctx.fillRect((sX * 100) + 1, (sY * 100) + 1, (sX * 100) + 9, (sY * 100) + 9); //draw snake part, here is the issue
  alert((sX * 100) + 9 + " " + sX + " " + (sX * 100) + 9); //debug statements
  alert((sX * 100) + 9);
  //}
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: The `ctx.fillRec()` line seems fine, as all the values are numbers. In your `alert` however, you introduce string concatenation, which causes a completely different result. `(5*100)+9` => `509`, but `" "+(5*100)+9` => `" 5009"`

Comment: You know `fillRect` is *fillRect(x, y, **width**, **height**)* right? Here you are drawing a 509 x 509 rectangle, with it's top left corner at coords 501, 501.

Comment: Burnt my Mjolnir... But duplicate of [html5 Canvas - FillRect() incorrectly draws the rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770994/html5-canvas-fillrect-incorrectly-draws-the-rectangle/43771190#43771190)